# PagingAndSortingRepository findByattributename issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a hotel entity object and I need to implement pagination for it's search. I tried implementing it through PagingAndSortingRepository interface. I have a no of columns in the entity. My solution works well for some attributes like "destinationcode" and "city" but when I try fetching results against "hotelcode" and "hotelname" I see in log that count query

```
 ("Hibernate: select count(hotel0_.destinationcode) as col_0_0_ from Hotel hotel0_ where hotel0_."HOTELNAME"=?")
```

is executed only and not the actual select query with no error or exception there. In case of working methods like findByCity I can see in log both count followed by Select queries.

All of the above 4 are of type String in the entity. My main entity is Hotel and it has an embeddedid called HotelPk which I think is just like standard entities that have composite keys.
so methods in my repository that work are

```
Page<Hotel> findByIdDestinationcode(String destinationCode, Pageable pageRequest);
```

and

```
Page<Hotel> findByCity(String state, Pageable pageRequest);
```

and the ones that don't work are

```
Page<Hotel> findByIdHotelcode(String hotelCode, Pageable pageRequest);
Page<Hotel> findByHotelname(String hotelName, Pageable pageRequest);
```

Signature of my repository is

```
public interface HotelRepository extends JpaRepository<Hotel, HotelPK>, PagingAndSortingRepository<Hotel, HotelPK> {
//...... methods are defined here.
}
```

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Hotel.findAll", query="SELECT h FROM Hotel h")
public class Hotel implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/*@EmbeddedId
private HotelPK id;*/
@Id
private String destinationcode;

private String hotelcode;

@Size(max = 20, message = "Column CITY cannot be more than 20 
characters.")
private String city;

//  @NotNull(message = "Column HOTELNAME cannot be null.")
@Size(max = 50, message = "Column HOTELNAME cannot be more than 50 
characters.")
private String hotelname;

/**
 * @return the destinationcode
 */
public String getDestinationcode() {
    return destinationcode;
}

/**
 * @param destinationcode the destinationcode to set
 */
public void setDestinationcode(String destinationcode) {
    this.destinationcode = destinationcode;
}

/**
 * @return the hotelcode
 */
public String getHotelcode() {
    return hotelcode;
}

/**
 * @param hotelcode the hotelcode to set
 */
public void setHotelcode(String hotelcode) {
    this.hotelcode = hotelcode;
}

/**
 * @return the city
 */
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

/**
 * @param city the city to set
 */
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

/**
 * @return the hotelname
 */
public String getHotelname() {
    return hotelname;
}

/**
 * @param hotelname the hotelname to set
 */
public void setHotelname(String hotelname) {
    this.hotelname = hotelname;
}
}
@Service(value = "HotelDao")
public class HotelDaoImpl implements HotelDao {
@Resource
private HotelRepository hotelRepository;

@Override
public Page<Hotel> searchHotel(String hotelCode, String hotelName, String 
      destinationCode, Pageable pageRequest) throws Exception {
    if(hotelCode!=null){
        return hotelRepository.findByHotelcode(Tools.padRight(hotelCode, 
3), pageRequest);
    }

    if(destinationCode!=null){
        return 
hotelRepository.findByDestinationcode(Tools.padRight(destinationCode, 3), 
pageRequest);
    }

    return hotelRepository.findByHotelname(hotelName, pageRequest);
}
}

public interface HotelRepository extends JpaRepository<Hotel, String> {
Page<Hotel> findByHotelcode(String hotelCode, Pageable pageRequest);

Page<Hotel> findByDestinationcode(String destinationCode, Pageable 
pageRequest);
Page<Hotel> findByHotelname(String hotelname, Pageable pageRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to extend `PagingAndSortingRepository<Hotel, HotelPK>`again as `JpaRepository<Hotel, HotelPK>` already extends it. You can check its implementation.

So define your repository like this.

```
public interface HotelRepository extends JpaRepository<Hotel, HotelPK> {
//...... methods are defined here.
}
```

Now, coming to your question, you can do the following.

```
  public Page<Hotel> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
    hotel.setHotelCode("HC");
    hotel.setHotelName("Hotel");
    return hotelRepository.findAll(Example.of(hotel),pageable);
  }
```

in your Service Layer

Comment: Not an elegant way, however

Comment: Thanks everyone, I moved the composite key inside the entity class and it is working now.